# A tag not respecting background color rgba opacity

Tags: css, background-color, opacity

I've got a weird situation:

In the snippet below, when I try and apply an `rgba` color to my a tag, it acts as if it is an `rgb` color, not an `rgba`. So the text background is solid, but the rest of the background (which is from the `span` not the `a`) has the correct opacity.

I know I can separate the `:hover` queries and it will solve the problem, but I'm wondering why it's doing this? What am I doing wrong?

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #00bcd4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00bcd4;
}
span:hover,
span:hover a {
  background: rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<span><a href="">Link</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
span:hover,
span:hover a {
  background: rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.5);
```

This means you set a 50% opacity background on the span **and** on the "a" inside of it. On the "a" you will see a 50% background, with the background of the span behind it, so it will appear darker.

Solution:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #00bcd4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #00bcd4;
}
span:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.5);
}
span:hover a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<span><a href="">Link</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply background to span only and color to the anchor link.

```
span:hover {
   background: rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.5);
}
span:hover a {
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7LL8d66/)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding   opacity:0.5; in

```
span:hover,
span:hover a {
  background: rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```